# What is the best way to determine a worker's current status since Taskrouter doesn't automatically update it in Multitasking mode?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-taskrouter

Taskrouter seems to leave a worker's activity status at Idle, even when they're in a call (we're only using voice at the moment). I tried disabling the other methods so only voice is active, but the result is the same.

I'd like to programmatically change the worker's status from Idle > Reserved > Busy > Wrap-Up when they answer calls like it used to function prior to Multitasking. Since there aren't individual callbacks at each step of the routing, I'm thinking about using the workspace's event call back, but that seems like a lot of extra work for my server. Is there a better way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[According to the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/multitasking#why-does-the-worker-not-change-activity-when-using-multitasking):

> #### Why does the Worker not change activity when using Multitasking?
>
> TaskRouter cannot assign any Tasks to workers unless a worker is in an available activity and since a worker needs to be able to work on multiple tasks when Multitasking is enabled, it’s important to keep the worker Idle. However, TaskRouter will keep track of the available capacity and will not assign more tasks than allowed for a worker.

So, when you are in multitasking mode your worker must stay idle (even if you've turned off the other channels, because this is about the mode you are set to, not what is available). It would be a bad idea to manually update the worker status because it would mess with TaskRouter keeping track.

Comment: Thank you, @philnash, for the quick response. Two follow-up questions: Could we update the status if we only plan on using voice? Can you recommend a way to get the actual current status of all workers to store info for data analytics if their activity is always showing idle?

Comment: If you are only going to use voice, then I would recommend not using multitasking mode and then the activities will return to updating. Unless you do want workers to be able to handle more than one voice call at a time? I'm not an expert on TaskRouter multitasking, but [the docs here say that if you want specific statistics then to contact support](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/multitasking#what-kind-of-statistics-are-provided-when-using-multitasking).

Comment: Thanks again! According to the Twilio Changelog [link](https://www.twilio.com/changelog/taskrouter-now-always-uses-multitasking-new-projects), you cannot disable multitasking any longer. I'll follow your previous link for more info. Thanks for helping this far. :-)

Comment: Oh, that is something I didn't realise! It's probably best to talk to support about how best to handle your needs now then.